# Manifest: deny install on tablets

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-screen-support

i would like to avoid installation of one of my app to tablets (up to 7" screens), because i'll create a specific version for tablets later.
Now i know i should use

```
<compatible-screens>
```

element inside manifest, but which combination of density and screen dimension should be removed from my list?

this is my manifest portion:

```
  <compatible-screens>

    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Release android app for handset only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640479/release-android-app-for-handset-only)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7649632/2948765) provides useful information about the actual screen sizes.